# How to escape single quotes ' In Oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I need to fetch record from Parameter table providing names, one of the name is  Total number of NE's .
My initial query was:

```
select * from PARAMETER
where name in ('Total number of NE's');--Gives Error

-- Does Give Error but doesn't fetch the record as well.
select * from PARAMETER
where name in ('Total number of NE''s');
```

How can i retrieve the data for this particular name, please help.

Comment: My mistake : select * from PARAMETER where name in ('Total number of NE''s');-- Does not  Give Error,but doesn't fetch the record as well.

Comment: your second example appears to be the correct way to escape the single quote.  perhaps the data does not match for another reason.

Comment: Does `select * from PARAMETER where name like 'Total number of%'` return your record?

Comment: Yes it does , but i have to use IN clause as there can be multiple names.

Comment: Maybe your problem is not related to special characters? Try to rebuild query like in this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/81c598/1).

Answer (score 3):

You can escape single quote with another single quote. Your query should look like

```
select * from PARAMETER
where name = 'Total number of NE''s';
```

(OR)

```
select * from PARAMETER
where name like 'Total number of NE%';
```

Also, since you are using `Oracle11g` you can use the [new quoting system](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/fundamentals.htm#sthref336) like

```
select * from PARAMETER
where name = q'!Total number of NE's!';
```

Comment: Hi ,Only the second option fetches result in this case. But i need to Use IN clause in my query.